# [Mongoose]How can I use the same model twice with two different schemas within app.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to access the same database/model for a sign-up and sign-in function but everytime I try to run my node app I get this error message "cannot overwrite 'user' model once compiled" here's my code:

```
//sign-up schema
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  username: String,
  password: String, 
  age: Number
});

var user = mongoose.model('users', Schema);

//sign-up login
app.post('/new', function(req, res) {
new user({
    _id: req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    age: req.body.age

}).save(function(err, doc){
    if(err) res.json(err);
    else res.send('Successfully Signed up');
  });
});

//login schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserDetail = new Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String
}, {
   collection: 'users'
});
var UserDetails = mongoose.model('users', UserDetail);

//login logic
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
process.nextTick(function() {
UserDetails.findOne({
  'username': username, 
}, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }

  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false);
  }

  if (user.password != password) {
    return done(null, false);
  }

  return done(null, user);
  });
});
}));
```

Comment: What's the point of this, since you can just lookup username and password using the same schema.

Comment: Sorry I Wasn't aware of this can you please help me, would you be able to give me an example. thanks for letting me know :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the same schema to lookup.

**Schema**

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    age: Number
});

var user = mongoose.model('users', Schema);
```

**Registration**

```
app.post('/new', function(req, res) {
    new user({
        _id: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        age: req.body.age
    }).save(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) res.json(err);
        else res.send('Successfully Signed up');
    });
});
```

**Login**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        user.findOne({
            'username': username
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false);
            }

            if (user.password !== password) { 
                return done(null, false); 
            }

            return done(null, user);
        });
    });
}));
```

If you don't want to return the password in the response, just add

```
delete user.password;
```

before the callback.

Comment: for some reason, it still isn't working, I've tested the authentication script alone, and it works fine. I'm unsure as to why it won't work in the actual application, do you have anything in mind?

Comment: I set a callback function for successful authentication and failed authentication and I got back a failed authentication.

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
    failureRedirect: '/loginFailure'
  })
);
 
app.get('/loginFailure', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Failed to authenticate');
});
 
app.get('/loginSuccess', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Successfully authenticated');
});